# get url value multiple if statments to change output

Tags: php

I have a high-score.php page, depending on which link is pressed there is a value added to the url.

**Example**

/high-score.php?score=image_set_1

To get the value of the url I use the following:

```
<?php
$pack=$_GET['score'];
?>
```

Then I can echo the results

```
<?php echo $pack; ?>
```

This will output: **image_set_1**

What I would like to do is change **image_set_1** to display **Fruit** and then the same for all the other Image_set

This is what I have so far

```
<?php
$pack=$_GET['score'];
if ($pack = "image_set_1"){
$pack = "Fruit cards";
}
else if ($pack = "image_set_2"){
$pack = "Number cards";
}
else if ($pack = "image_set_3"){
$pack = "Animal cards";
}
else if ($pack = "image_set_4"){
$pack = "Vegetable cards";
}
?>
```

The problem is the output is always **fruit** no matter what the url value is.

If I change the code from **else if** to just **if** then it displays just vegetable cards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct [**Comparison Operator**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is `==` not `=`

```
if ($pack = "image_set_1") {
    // code
}
```

Needs to be:

```
if ($pack == "image_set_1") {
    // ---^
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `==` to compare values, a single `=` sets a value.

```
if ($pack == "image_set_1"){
$pack = "Fruit cards";
}
```

Like so.

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about comparison operators, I really had no idea!